# Dictionary.ContainsKey When Key is Another Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, .net-6.0

I'm trying to answer this leetcode problem:

https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/

I understand it's hashmap problem, and I've elected to do something as follows:

```
IList<IList<string>> GroupAnagrams(string[] strs)
{
    Dictionary<SortedDictionary<char, int>, List<string>> history = new Dictionary<SortedDictionary<char, int>, List<string>>();
    foreach (string phrase in strs)
    {
        SortedDictionary<char, int> signature = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
        foreach (char c in phrase.ToCharArray())
        {
            if (signature.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                signature[c] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                signature.Add(c, 1);
            }
        }
        if (history.ContainsKey(signature))
        {
            history[signature].Add(phrase);
        }
        else
        {
            history[signature] = new List<string>();
            history[signature].Add(phrase);
        }
    }

    IList<IList<string>> result = new List<IList<string>>();
    foreach (var pair in history)
    {
        result.Add(pair.Value);
    }

    return list;
}
```

The idea being that signature is a counter for characters. If two phrases have the same signature then they are an anagram. However, I noticed while stepping through the code via the debugger that the method call history.ContainsKey(signature) never returns true. Even when monitoring the locals in the debugger across iterations. I wondered if this was because signature should have been a SortedDictionary, but that didn't seem to have an effect. In fact, when I look at the locals for history, it seemingly has duplicate keys. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: People usually run into some confusion when using various object types as keys because they skip over the part where by default a class descended from object essentially uses its memory address to determine if it is equal to another object. You could have two dictionaries A and B, both  with exactly the same contents `a["a"] = 1; b["a"] = 1`, store A as the key in a third dictionary `c[a] = null` and then ask the dictionary C if it contains B and it will say no: `c.ContainsKey(b) //false`

Comment: To solve that challenge I think I would perhaps use a single `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, I'd sort the chars of the key and store the word under the list at the sorted key. That way `tan` and `Nat` both become stored in the list under the key of `ant` when their chars are sorted. `dict[string.Concat("nat".OrderBy(a=>a))] = new(); dict.ContainsKey(string.Concat("tan".OrderBy(a=>a))); //true`

Comment: *typo `Nat` -> `nat`

Comment: You can solve this with a single LINQ query: `var result = strs.Select(x => (x, new string(x.OrderBy(y => y).ToArray()))).GroupBy(x => x.Item2).Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Item1).ToList()).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what's going on?

Dictionaries (and sorted dictionaries) are not compared by value but by reference equality.  The only way `ContainsKey` will return true is if the actual object passed as its argument is present in the dictionary.

In other words, this code prints "false" twice:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Dictionary<char, int>() == new Dictionary<char, int>());
Console.WriteLine(new Dictionary<char, int> { 'a', 1 } == new Dictionary<char, int> { 'a', 1 });
```